# Markers in google maps don't draw

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm coding using react + firestore 9 on an application that has to render a google map and then depending on the query it shows some markers.

I've been trying to get the aplication to draw some basic markers with some data I'm fetching from the database, the query is executed as quickly as it can, I've tried a lot of solutions but the map is not rendering the markers for me. The following is the code I'm using in the component:

```
      function fetchMarkers(){
            var markerData = [];
            getDocs(query(collection(db, "places")))
            .then((foo) => {        
                foo.forEach((doc) => {
                    markerData.push(doc.data())
                })
            })
            return markerData;
        }
    
        var arrayData = [];
    
        export default function Map() {
            fetchMarkers().then((value) => {
                arrayData = value;
                console.log(arrayData)
            })
   return (
            <div id="map">
               <LoadScript
                   googleMapsApiKey={apiKey}>
                   <GoogleMap
                      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                      center={center}
                      zoom={13}
                      options={{ fullscreenControl: false, mapTypeControl: false, streetViewControl: false, styles: [{ elementType: "labels", featureType: "poi", stylers: [{ visibility: "off", }], }], }}>
                    {arrayData.map((marker) =>
                       <Marker
                          key={marker.id}
                          position={{
                             lat: marker.latitud,
                             lng: marker.longitud
                          }}
                       />)
                    }
                 </GoogleMap>
            </LoadScript>
        </div>
)
```

What is happening here is that the page is loading before the arrayData fills with the contents of the document related to it, and it's still not placing the markers after.

I'd appreciate a lot your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using [react state variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) to contain your data from the database then make that state as the condition or the value of your Marker?  This way, it will sure to update the value used in the marker when the states are changed.

Comment: Yes, that is the way I solved this problem, I used this.state to create a variable within the component that got filled up as you searched for markers with the desired conditions. That way, when the state changes the component detects it and updates itself :-)